# Why can I not view my emails as a conversation within folders in Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes

I noticed that within folders in Lotus Notes, I am not able to view my emails as a conversation.

Is this a bug or limitation?

Comment: I had the same problem than you then I found this article : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/sent-received/
Try it, it is working great on my lotus notes version 8.5

Answer (score 1):

Which version of notes?

When I used Notes 6.5 you were able to do this. It was not always straightforward (nothing in Notes is, though).

Comment: I am using version 8.5.1, seems to work in the inbox but nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common causes for this.

1. The documents were created before the template was upgraded to R8, so they are missing the $TUA field. This is needed to track the conversations.
2. As you mention it works in the inbox but not elsewhere, it is possible you didn't upgrade the folder design. Try replace the design with the mail template you use, only click on "Upgrade folder design". During the upgrade select automatic upgrade.

The following Technote covers other issues in relation to $TUA.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21284223